# How to get instant changes in background from private api in mobile app?

Tags: node.js, api, xamarin, mobile, background

I am planning to create a mobile application for android and ios users, i think i will take a try with xamarin since i will be alone on this project and i don't have a lots of time.

I want that the mobile app for both platform get datas from the api, then if there is new datas available we notify the user by a notification.

How the mobile will work in that kind of project? I mean should i make a background service then check every x seconds/minutes by http request? In that case which time interval? Should i use websockets instead for this case?

The app might be used by many people, so i would to know the scenario in this kind of project: Getting very fast changes, without overload the server due to too many connects or whatever else.

I'm confused about this and i need some lights around, any mobile application/server experiences related would be apprecied!

**EDIT:**

As suggered by an user, here additional infos:

- The api is homemade, restful using JWT made in NodeJS.
- Each users on their device should get messages from server asap, even when the app is in background/closed.
- Maybe in the future a way to send messages between users themselves.

Answer (score 2):

**You have to implement push notification.**

It is quite easy to implement this in xamarin. just send the push notification to the device and on the notification received call back send the API request to retrieve the updated data.

Here is the document for sending push notification from custom API.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/push/pushapi

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a mobile developer, so take this with a grain of salt.

The answer to this really depends on what you're doing, which informs how often to check the API. If it's a messaging app, for example, you could have it check every couple minutes to see if there are undelivered messages, then check more frequently for the next X minutes (to facilitate a conversation in real time).

If it's a GPS navigation app to be used while driving, you'd need much more frequent requests.

As for the API, that also depends on what type of API and the number of requests you can make to it. Is it a commercial API that you get x number of calls per hour on? Is it an API that you built? Etc.

Basically, you need to give more information in order to get more specific answers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You're right, i will update the post to precise the goal of the program and things, it concerne a private api made in nodejs by myself, the owner of the server will save content in database, then the client should get it asap and once received deleting it from database.

Comment: Since you're hosting the API, the frequency will depend on the number of calls your API can handle. Maybe do some testing to determine that, which will inform your decisions on how frequently to check? Good luck!